# In AngularJS how to redirect from on controller to another?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Assume I've a AngularJS with a state/controller URL of:

```
url: '/myurl'
```

While in a different controller (eg. on a button press), I do a:

```
$window.location.href = '/myurl';
```

To jump to another page. However is there a "AngularJS native" way of switching between pages?

Comment: Are you using `ng-routes` or `ui-router`? And which version of both are you using?

Answer (score 1):

every page has $state which you can transfer data between states as well. use the flowing function to change the state and inject it as a dependency in your controller first.

```
 $state.go('your-new-state', {
        ...params 
    });
```

use ui router.

Answer (score 1):

You could to do it in different ways. Depending on what you want and what kind of router you are using:

#### If your are using `ng-route`

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/main' , {templateUrl: 'main.html'})
    .when('/somePage', {templateUrl: 'somePage.html'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/main'});

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($location) {
    $scope.click = function () {
        $location.path('/somePage');
    }
});
```

#### If your are using `ui-router`

```
$stateProvider
    .state('main', {
        url: '/main',
        templateUrl: 'main.html'
    })
    .state('somePage', {
        url: '/somePage/:someParam',
        templateUrl: 'somePage.html'
    });

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($state) {
    $scope.click = function () {
        $state.go('somePage', { someParam: 'someValue'});
    }
});
```

#### If your are using `ui-router` >= Version `1.0.0`

This shows you how to handle a state based redirect. This could be helpful in some cases when you have to handle a redirect on that route based on some conditions.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('main', {
        url: '/main',
        templateUrl: 'main.html',
        redirectTo: (trans) => {
            if (trans.params().redirectToSomePage) {
                return { state: 'somePage', params: { someParam: 'someValue' } };
            }
        }
    })
    .state('somePage', {
        url: '/somePage/:someParam',
        templateUrl: 'somePage.html'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $location if you're using ngRoute

for example

```
$location.path('/myurl');
```

mind that, you must inject $location in your controller